# Animate View on keyboard open (Titanium Mobile)

Tags: javascript, ipad, animation, keyboard, titanium-mobile

Developing in Titanium mobile.

Are views/windows suppose to automatically animate when the keyboard open/closes? Currently it is not working for me. When my text field gains focus, it ends up behind the keyboard. I tried firing a custom event on my input fields focus so that I could animate everything up myself, but it doesn't happen with the keyboard, and therefore isn't as smooth.

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, if you use a scrollView instead of normal View. When the textfield in scrollView get focus the scrollview will automatically adjust its position to make the textfield and keyboard visible on screen.

I have tested it on iPhone but need to cross check it on iPad in SDK 1.8.2.